# Replacing url param with name instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to have the url `http://localhost:3000/projects/"nameofproject"`

My routes

```
resources :projects, param: :project_name
```

My controller

```
def show
    @project = Project.find_by(project_name: params[:project_name])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. Its an easy way to use [Semantic URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL) in rails.

Comment: do you have a good tutorial, ive looked at the documentation and videos and still not sure how to implement

Comment: I recommend taking a look at their [guide](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html).